# Forçar o Javascript cancelar cadastro de campo com required (HTML 5)?

Tags: javascript, html5, backbone.js

Tenho um campo de cadastro que são de preenchimento obrigatório através HTML5. Porém, ao clicar no botão cancelar cadastro, o HTML5 não deixa o Javascript retornar a página anterior! =( Obriga que eu preencha aquele campo do required.

Como proceder?

```
'click button#back': function (evt) {
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            Backbone.history.navigate("/InstanciaManager", {trigger : true});
        },
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em português! Você pode usar algo com localStorage ou sessionStorage para fazer isso. Veja em [Webstorage](http://tableless.com.br/web-storage-html5/)

Comment: Posta o código do HTML. **Talvez** você não tenha definido o button como `[type=button]`. Isso pode ocasionar problemas, pois alguns navegadores poderão identificar que você está tentando fazer um submit com o botão que não especificou o `type`. Experiência própria :)

Comment: Obrigada mutlei e Wallace, funcionou! =)

Comment: O que funcionou?

Comment: O type do button e alterar a ordem no JS! Além disso, havia outro problema p funcionar.. hahaha Obrigada, gente

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz o `evt.stopImmediatePropagation()` você impede o evento que foi disparado de continuar executando, ou seja, você impede o retrocesso à página anterior.

Inverta a ordem dos comandos, desse modo:

```
'click button#back': function (evt) {
        Backbone.history.navigate("/InstanciaManager", {trigger : true});
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
```